# DialogFlow "remind me every 4 hours query"

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am trying to create a reminder app on dialogFlow.
I have variety of user phrases screenshot given below. I am facing an issue in my one of user phrase highlighted in red .

[image: dialogFlow image]

When a user say

```
Remind me every 4 hours to bla bla bla
```

It returns me date_time param as 4pm, but I am expected it to return current time + 4 hours.

[image: dialogFlow try]

is there anything wrong I have done?
I welcome suggestion how to achieve this in any alternative way

Answer (score 1):

To pick the hours you can use `@sys.duration`[image]